# Web parser in Javascript like BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html-parsing

I came from `Python`, where with `beautiful soup` you can parse the entire `html tree` without creating `get` requests in **external web pages**. I'm looking for the same in `javascript`, but I've only found `jsdom` and `jssoup` (which seems unused) and if I'm correct, they only allow you to make requests.
I want a library in `js` which allows me to parse the entire `html tree` without getting `CORS` policy errors, that is, without making request, just parsing it.

How can I do this?

Comment: CORS error come from browser events. Something in Node.js should not have those issues. In browser you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) for converting text into an object you can traverse. I would suggest looking into puppeteer as well for accomplishing web scraping / automation.

Comment: How do you expect to parse some HTML (assuming it's from another site) if you don't request the HTML? Are you doing this on the front-end on a server?

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch domparser will work in an external web page?

Comment: @Andy yup, it's from another web site. with bs4 in python you can take if without a request, so i thought in js would be something like that

Comment: I'd imagine under the hood BS4 actually makes a call to get the HTML. It doesn't just "magically appear." The fact that it does all the hard work for you doesn't mean it doesn't happen at some point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a browser context, you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
const html = "<h1>title</h1>";
const parser = new DOMParser();
const parsed = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
console.log(parsed.firstChild.innerText); // "title"
```

and in node you can use [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser):

```js
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

const html = "<h1>title</h1>";
const parsed = parse(html);
console.log(parsed.firstChild.innerText); // "title"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! will this work in external web sites?

Comment: @Omar can you clarify what you mean by "external web sites"?

Comment: for wxample, this website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289275/web-parser-in-javascript-like-beautifulsoup-in-python. how can i parse its html?

Comment: First you'll need to get the html source for that URL, most likely by making a request to the URL (watch out for CORS if you're in a browser). Once you have the html as a string you can use the relevant code from above to parse it

Comment: Can this be done via cURL? Can we get external URL consumed via cURL and then created a dom tree in NODE environment? Any example of this?